# Cannot delay two JavaScript actions on iPhone / iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, html, spinner

I display a loading spinner to reload a custom pdf reader (in html 5) after each rotation of the device. It works well on an android device and when i simulate a rotation on desktop device, but on the iPad, I cannot see the spinner, it's as if the actions showing the spinner / reloading the pdf reader/ hiding the spinner are  executed at a "one shot". 
I've tried to delay the pdf reloading until the spinner is shown but it's the same thing. 
Here is the sequence of actions :

```
window.onorientationchange = function() {
           launchSpinnerThenRotate();
}

function launchSpinnerThenRotate(){
    alert(" i'll launchSpinnerThenRotate");
    showSpinner();
    setTimeout(rotatePdfReader(),1000);
}
```

I've tried both js and jquery functions to show / hide spinner always with the same effect

```
function showSpinner(){
    //$('#pdfReaderSpinner').css("visibility" , "visible");
    document.getElementById('pdfReaderSpinner').style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById('pdfReaderSpinner').style.zIndex = 100000000;
}
```

I don't think that the problem is in spinner, I can show it correctly at the first launching of the page, but I had to show the spinner in the document.ready function :

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var target = document.getElementById('loadingSpinner');
    spinner = new Spinner({top: 0, left: 0,color:'red'}).spin(target);
    showSpinner();
});

$(window).load(function(){
    initPdfReader();
    hideSpinner();
});
```

Comment: Are you sure you're setting the z-index high enough ?

Comment: The z-index needs to be at least 1x10^15 to be even vaguely visible.

Comment: I think just setting it to one googol will do ?

Comment: No, the problem wasn't in the z-index, I've added it optionally to be sure. I don't set other's objects z-index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
setTimeout(rotatePdfReader(),1000);
```

to this:

```
setTimeout(rotatePdfReader,1000);
```

You want to pass the reference to the function to setTimeout so it can be called in 1 second. Currently you are passing the result of the function to setTimeout.

Comment: great !!  that's magical. Even if it doesn't explain the different behaviour between iOs mobile devices and the others